# Monotouch Camera Image Capture and Upload

Tags: image, file-upload, xamarin.ios, capture, photos

I would like to be able to capture an image (or choose an image from the photo library) and upload it to a remote server using Monotouch.  I am not sure how to obtain and encode the image or how to upload the image and I am having difficulty finding relevant instructions.   Can you help me get started?   Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [UIImagePickerController](http://www.go-mono.org/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIImagePickerController).  [Here](http://www.martinbowling.com/post/Screen-Cast-Using-UIImagePickerController-in-MonoTouch.aspx) is a screencast on how to use it in Monotouch.

Comment: Awesome!  Now for the upload.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a full example in MonoTouch

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/UI/Camera.cs